# Python variables are missing in the for loop

Tags: python

Part of my code involves accessing the pre-defined variables in a for loop. However, trying to access the already existing variables in a for loop doesn't seem to work:

```
import itertools
def f(x):
    x1, x2 = itertools.tee(x)
    print(list(x1), list(x2))
    for i in range(1):
        print(list(x1), list(x2))

f(iter([1,2]))
```

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: You know that `range(1)` just contains a single value, `0`, right?  You could replace it with `i = 0` and get rid of the loop if that's really what you want.

Answer (score 0):

the problem as `x1` and `x2` are iterable and when you are `print(list(x1), list(x2))` the iterable are gone  no have longer `next` so you should remove this line

```
import itertools

def f(x): 
    x1, x2 = itertools.tee(x) 
    #print(list(x1), list(x2)) 
    print(type(x1), type(x2)) 
    for i in range(1): 
        print(i) 
        print(list(x1), list(x2)) 

f([1,2])
```

output

```
<class 'itertools._tee'> <class 'itertools._tee'>
0
[1, 2] [1, 2]
```